# How to set up Omnipay with Laravel?

Tags: paypal, laravel-5, omnipay

I am using this packet:

https://github.com/barryvdh/laravel-omnipay

In my controller I added:

```
$params = [
            'amount' => '10',
            'issuer' => 22,
            'description' => 'desc',
            'returnUrl' => URL::action('PurchaseController@returnApi', [43]),
        ];
        $response = Omnipay::purchase($params)->send();

        if ($response->isSuccessful()) {
            // payment was successful: update database
            print_r($response);
        } elseif ($response->isRedirect()) {
            // redirect to offsite payment gateway
            return $response->getRedirectResponse();
        } else {
            // payment failed: display message to customer
            echo $response->getMessage();
        }
```

Here is my omnipay.php conf file:

```
<?php

return array(

    /** The default gateway name */
    'gateway' => 'PayPal_Express',

    /** The default settings, applied to all gateways */
    'defaults' => array(
        'testMode' => true,
    ),

    /** Gateway specific parameters */
    'gateways' => array(
        'PayPal_Express' => array(
            'username' => '',
            'landingPage' => array('billing', 'login'), 
        ),
    ),

);
```

But get this error:

> call_user_func_array() expects parameter 1 to be a valid callback,
>   class 'Omnipay\Common\GatewayFactory' does not have a method
>   'purchase'

Anyone can help me set this?
I created app on paypal and have details about it but don't know how to set it with this API...

Answer (score 2):

I recommend that you switch from PayPal Express to PayPal REST.  It is newer and has better documentation.

I have looked through the laravel-omnipay package and I can't see a use case for it.  I would just code to the omnipay package directly.

I recommend that you create a unique transaction ID for each transaction and provide that as part of the URLs for returnUrl and cancelUrl so that you can identify which transaction you are dealing with in the return and cancel handlers.

I think that you are taking the examples in the laravel-omnipay package too literally. You don't need or want those echo statements there.  You should be capturing the response from purchase() even if it is a redirectResponse and doing a getTransactionReference() check on it, because you will need that transaction reference later, e.g. for transaction lookup.  You should store it in the transaction record that you created before calling purchase().

Answer (score 2):

You may use

```
use Omnipay\Omnipay;
```

in your controller, change it to

```
use Omnipay;
```